# Obj-class-ref error when compiling for an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5

```
Ld /Users/rajeshmedampudi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sampleResource-flngddqnaawregcrrshzpianssjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleResource.app/sampleResource normal i386
    cd /Users/rajeshmedampudi/Dropbox/Work/iphone/sampleResource
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/rajeshmedampudi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sampleResource-flngddqnaawregcrrshzpianssjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/rajeshmedampudi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sampleResource-flngddqnaawregcrrshzpianssjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/rajeshmedampudi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sampleResource-flngddqnaawregcrrshzpianssjc/Build/Intermediates/sampleResource.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleResource.build/Objects-normal/i386/sampleResource.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/rajeshmedampudi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sampleResource-flngddqnaawregcrrshzpianssjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleResource.app/sampleResource

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_User", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AuthenticationViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppHelpers", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

this is the error I am getting when I try to run the file ... I have imported those classes from another project into this one which was non arc based and converted to ARC. I got this error after successfully removing all the references to autorelease and retains from it.

Comment: duplicate variables are declared in some other class. refer and clean the target then run the project...

Comment: i dont think i have any duplicate variables.... they were simply not included into the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try Product->Clean?
Or restarting XCode?
Did you make sure you've included everything in the Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources? Xcode does this for you, but sometimes it misses things.

Comment: Just so future folks can know, which one of my suggestions worked?

Comment: the second one .. to add the files to the compile sources. i did not have a look at it before.. missed it somehow.